# Disabled button still calls target

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a system setup in my application where a user can pinch views to expand them to full screen (like Flipboard).  However, when I do so, I want to disable some buttons that are visible in both modes.  Normally it works fine but it fails in the following edge case:

1) Push button in non-zoomed mode (don't release)

2) Pinch view to enlarge, and wait for it to finish animating.  The button then gets its `userInteractionEnabled`  set to `NO`.

3) Release button, and the target function is called anyway.  I put a breakpoint in the target function and used lldb to check the button and `userInteractionEnabled` was indeed set to `NO`.

Am I wrong in expecting that a button that is disabled should not fire its target?  Should I check this in the target function?

Here is the function that actually disables the buttons, just in case you want to see (*edit*: there appears to be some confusion.  There is nothing going wrong with the below code, I just included it to be thorough.)

```
//The function that disables the buttons
- (void)disableButtons:(SO2MenuButtons)buttons
{
    UIView *view = nil;
    if(buttons & SO2Mokuji)
    {
        view = [self.view viewWithTag:151];
        view.alpha = 0.5;
        view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    if(buttons & SO2NoteView)
    {
        view = [self.view viewWithTag:152];
        view.alpha = 0.5;
        view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    //etc, etc...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed the above to this with the same result

```
- (void)disableButtons:(SO2MenuButtons)buttons
{
    UIButton *view = nil;
    if(buttons & SO2Mokuji)
    {
        view = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:151];
        view.enabled = NO;
    }
    if(buttons & SO2NoteView)
    {
        view = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:152];
        view.enabled = NO;
    }
    //etc, etc...
}
```

**EDIT** It seems I didn't clearly convey what the problem is, so I threw together a simple project that demonstrates the problem.  You can download it [here](http://www.filedropper.com/test_14) (Depending on when you read this message, the previous link may have expired).  The problem is that the button is still firing its target method AFTER it has been disabled.  After looking at what the above page looks like I apologize for using filedropper...I don't know what the popular way to share projects is these days >_<.  Don't click on the big green download button, click on the one that says "Download this file"

Comment: what's your problem ,you want to enable button?

Comment: @Dinesh I don't want it to fire the target method after I disable it.

Comment: your problem is fire the target method when button disable state..!

Comment: Normally your Code should work fine... You can try [view setEnabled: NO];

Comment: @Tobi Just an enum (bit flags) I use to determine which buttons to disable

Comment: can you set "view.userInteractionEnabled = NO" too?

Comment: @Tobi I already tried both of them.  I combined them also, and it still has the same behavior (its as if the touchesEnded function in UIKit is not checking if it is disabled or not)

Comment: Mhh... that's strange... can you refresh the button? A workaround would be, that you check in your Action, if button is enabled or not ;-)

Comment: @Tobi Yes, I know this workaround but I wanted to see if I had to do that or not because it's a pain and I don't want to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10582/discussion-between-borrrden-and-tobi)

Comment: would the event "UIControlEventTouchDown" work?

Comment: @Tobi In theory, yes, but then if the user presses the wrong button they have no chance to correct their mistake (i.e. move their finger away and release).  Anyway, I found a provisional solution.  I will post it as an answer and accept it if another one is not found soon.

Comment: ahh, okay... i understand :-) now, i'm out... i don't have any solution in my pocket :-D

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Got a similar issue with a disabled button still triggering hander.

Comment: @1ndivisible I mentioned my workaround in my answer below.  Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue completely.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I saw. Looking for a fix, not a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around this by setting `exclusiveTouch` to `YES` on those buttons.  That way the user cannot pinch the views while holding the button.  Of course, this doesn't really address the original issue so I won't accept this answer for now.  If no one posts an answer for a while I will accept this one though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are using the bitwise AND operator &, while what you want is the logical AND operator &&.

Comment: Nope, I want to use bitwise.  SO2MenuButtons is a bit field and it helps me determine which buttons to disable.